# Merging Objects in React State

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am receiving new data points in real time, and I am trying to use the react `useState` hook to update my data. There may be several hundred thousand points, so updates need to be efficient. The structure of my state looks roughly like this:

```
{
  "graph1": {
    "line1": [[x1, y1], [x2, y2],..., [x100, y100]],
    "line2": [[x1, y1], [x2, y2],..., [x200, y200]],
    "line3": [[x1, y1], [x2, y2],..., [x900, y900]]
  },
  "graph2": {
    "line1": [[x1, y1], [x2, y2],..., [x100, y100]],
    "line2": [[x1, y1], [x2, y2],..., [x200, y200]]
  }
}
```

Where the `xi, yi` are just floating point numbers. I receive updates in a similar format, for example:

```
{
  "graph1": {
    "line1": [[x101, y101]],
    "line3": [[x901, y901], [x902, y902]],
    "line4": [[x1, y1]],
  },
  "graph2": {
    "line1": [[x101, y101]],
  }
}
```

And I would like to update my state so that it looks like this:

```
{
  "graph1": {
    "line1": [[x1, y1], [x2, y2],..., [x101, y101]],
    "line2": [[x1, y1], [x2, y2],..., [x200, y200]],
    "line3": [[x1, y1], [x2, y2],..., [x902, y902]],
    "line4": [[x1, y1]]
  },
  "graph2": {
    "line1": [[x1, y1], [x2, y2],..., [x101, y101]],
    "line2": [[x1, y1], [x2, y2],...,  [x200, y200]]
  }
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this than with a mess of spread operators? i.e.

```
setGraphs(xs => ({
  ...xs,
  "graph1": {
    ...xs.graph1,
    "line1": [...xs.graph1.line1, ...new_data.graph1.line1],
    // etc
})
```

In particular, with the spread operator approach, it's not clear to me how to handle a dynamic set of keys - for example, the new `"line4"` key in the update above.

I have full control over both the structure of the data and the structure of my react code, so if there is a more idiomatic way to achieve the same goal I would love to hear that too.

Answer (score 2):

You could regenerate the state and reset it. Your solution only works when you know all the possible keys but otherwise, we need to merge them by iteration. Like this:

```
setGraph(graph => {
  Object.keys(newData).forEach(g => {
    Object.keys(newData[g]).forEach(l => {
      if (graph[g][l]) {
        graph[g][l] = [...graph[g][l], ...newData[g][l]);
      } else {
        graph[g][l] = newData[g][l];
      }
    });
  });
  return graph;
});
```

Comment: How efficient is this? If my existing state is large, but `newData` is small, will this run quickly?

Comment: I doubt that the update data will be large. This is O(n*m), but still if the update data is not big, it will be fast.

Comment: What are n,m here? For my application, typically, the existing state `graph` will have 10000-100000 points, and the update data `newData` will have 10-100 points.

Comment: n: number of graphs, m: number of lines. we can't go faster than O(n*m) here. if it's 10-100 points, it will be very fast though.

Comment: The number of graphs and the number of lines in the existing state, or in the new update message? (I'm mostly worried about doing work for each point in the existing state, if the update time here depends only on the size of the update message and not on the size of the existing state, I'm quite happy)

Comment: In the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Spread operator is the best way to update objects or arrays. One of the new features in ECMA Script 2015 and above.